# Java serialize overwrite the current file

Tags: java, serialization

Currently I'm serializing an ArrayList to a file like this:

```
   FileOutputStream fosAlarms = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oosAlarms = null;
    try {
        fosAlarms = openFileOutput("alarms.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oosAlarms = new ObjectOutputStream(fosAlarms);
        oosAlarms.writeObject(alarms);
        System.out.println("Serialisation done");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oosAlarms != null && fosAlarms != null) {
            try {
                oosAlarms.close();
                fosAlarms.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this works as intended. But I want this method to overwrite current file (if there is any). If I remove an object from the array and serialize it again, the removed object persists. How do I do this?

Comment: What is openFileOutput doing?

Comment: You've left out the only code of any relevance. Serialization has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this constructor of `FileOutputStream` and set `append` to false.

[FileOutputStream(String, boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

So... I guess you need to change a bit your method `openFileOutput`.